# How can I transform rotation to FVector in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

How can I transform `MainComponent->GetComponentRotation()` to `FVector`?

Do I have to use `AddForce()` for child components?

I need to get its *rotation vector*. How do I get it correctly?

Comment: Should be able to use `MainComponent->GetComponentRotation().Vector()` or just `MainComponent->GetComponentForwardVector()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use either

```
MainComponent->GetComponentRotation().Vector();
```

or

```
MainComponent->GetComponentForwardVector();
```

See documentation - [GetComponentRotation()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/GetComponentRotation/) and [GetComponentForwardVector()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/GetForwardVector/) for more details.